# Error al leer datos utlizando la librería Scanner

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>   at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main

El código es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication2{
     public static void main(String []args){
           Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
           int nom;
           int cosa;
           System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre:");
           nom = w.nextInt();

           System.out.println("gckg");
           cosa = w.next();
     }
}
```

Comment:      

Answer (score 2):

El error se produce porque estás intentando leer un entero, `e.nextInt()`, y lo que has introducido es un caracter `c`. Te recomiendo, para que te evites este tipo de errores, que lees la entrada del usuario como `String` y luego en el código validar que realmente se corresponde con a lo que esperas. Ejemplo:

```
int num;
String entrada = w.nextLine();
if (entrada.matches("\\d+")) {
    // como la entrada es un número entero
    num = Integer.parseInt(entrada);
} else {
    // Pedirle al usuario que vuelva a entrar la información
}
```